# ReSharper does not recognize the required keyword

Tags: resharper

The following code compiles fine. But ReSharper does not recognize the word required. If I suspend ReSharper, then required is no longer red.

[image]

Is there something I need to turn on/set to get this accepted?

Comment: what does your Resharper | About Resharper window say at the moment?

Comment: Version 2022.1 - updating now...

Comment: Now 2022.3.2 and it's fixed. Had to bounce Visual Studio after the update. If you make the version updating an answer, happy to accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this Jetbrains blogpost](https://blog.jetbrains.com/dotnet/2022/08/02/resharper-2022-2-released/), ReSharper version **2022.2** was the first to support `required` :

> ### C# 11 support
>
> This release brings support for several more features from the C# 11
> preview:
>
> - ReSharper 2022.2 is now aware of the required keyword for members inside a `class`, `struct`, or `record` type, and provides additional
>   support for the “required” keyword in code completion. We’ve also
>   added a new Add initializer for required members quick-fix for cases
>   where you’ve created a type’s object, but haven’t initialized the
>   members yet.